# Reading Text file and extracting data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to read a text file in python. The file has data as shown below:

%

```
O04444
(T2 D=12.7 CR=0. - ZMIN=-11.5 - flat end mill)
(T3 D=4.978 CR=0. TAPER=118deg - ZMIN=-22. - drill)
N10 G90 G94 G17
N15 G21
N20 G53 G0 Z0.

(Face2)
N30 T2 M6
N35 S1380 M3
N40 G54
N45 M8
N60 G0 X108.255 Y-46.214
N65 G43 Z15. H2
N70 T3
N75 G0 Z5.
N80 G1 Z-0.73 F355.6
N85 G18 G3 X106.985 Z-2. I-1.27 K0.
N90 G1 X100.
N95 X0.
N100 G17 G2 Y-36.199 I0. J5.008
N105 G1 X100.
N110 G3 Y-26.184 I0. J5.008
N115 G1 X0.
N120 G2 Y-16.168 I0. J5.008
N125 G1 X100.
N130 G3 Y-6.153 I0. J5.008
N135 G1 X0.
N140 G18 G3 X-1.27 Z-0.73 I0. K1.27
N145 G0 Z15.
N150 M5
N155 G53 G0 Z0.

(Drill3)
N165 M9
N170 M1
N175 T3 M6
N180 S5850 M3
N185 G54
N190 M8
N200 G17
N205 G0 X80. Y-40.
N210 G43 Z15. H3
N215 T2
N225 G0 Z5.
N230 G98 G81 X80. Y-40. Z-22. R3. F584.2
N235 Y-25.
N240 Y-10.
N245 G80
N250 G0 Z15.
N255 M5
N260 G53 G0 Z0.

(2D Pocket1)
N270 M9
N275 M1
N280 T2 M6
N285 S1380 M3
N290 G54
N295 M8
N310 G0 X47.315 Y7.644
N315 G43 Z15. H2
```

I want to split this file into 4 different files. It should be separated whenever there is an empty line in between. I am new to python. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about reading the file line by line and change the output file after reading an empty line? Please show what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use re to split immediately:

```
import re
for x in re.split('\n\n',open('bla.txt').read()):
    open(x.split("\n")[0].strip('()').replace(" ","_"),'w').write(x)
```

the `x.split` part is to determine filename according to the header, you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is straight-forward. You can just have a counter that keeps on iterating over every line in the file.

```
i = 0
for line in open("somefile", "r"):
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        continue
    with open("new_file{}".format(i), "w") as new_file:
        new_file.write(line)
    i += 1
```

If you want to use some more advanced features of the language you can drop the LOC used and get rid of ugly if/else statements

```
lines = open("somefile", "r").readlines()
non_empty = [line for line in lines if len(line.strip()) != 0]
for i, line in enumerate(non_empty):
    with open("new file{}".format(i), "w") as new_file:
        new_file.write(line)
```